# I'm trying to use multiple joins to create atable but I'm getting the same table as the output/

Tags: sql, join, alias

```
select 
    Date, Home, Away, Umpire 
from 
    Match
join 
    Team on Match.Home = Team.TeamId 
join 
    Team as T on Match.Away = T.TeamId
join 
    Umpire on Match.Umpire = Umpire.UmpireId
```

I'm trying to join `Team` and `Umpire` tables with `Match` first, I get an error because I was using `Team` twice, so I created an alias `T`. But when I executed this, I'm just getting the `Match` table as the output.

What do you think the problem is?

Comment: this is because you are only `select`ing columns from `Match` table

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you didn't get what @vkp points out:

```
select 
    Match.*, Team.*, T.*, Umpire.* 
from 
    Match
join 
    Team on Match.Home = Team.TeamId 
join 
    Team as T on Match.Away = T.TeamId
join 
    Umpire on Match.Umpire = Umpire.UmpireId
```